# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calendar_ui'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I installed KivyCalendar with `pip install KivyCalendar` command. But when I import KivyCalendar, I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calendar_ui'`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: maybe [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518358/getting-error-no-module-named-calendar-ui-even-though-kivycalendar-has-been) this link

Comment: thanks, didn't find that

Comment: @proger23 Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @xjcl no actually, I cannot use the calendar widget in python 3, it is usable only on python 2.